# The verb after suggest

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I wrote:

> I suggest you point to what A should return and match[**ing**?] it with the output of B in README

My complete suggestion is:

> I suggest you that you point to what A should return and say the user to match it with the output of B in README

Does my original sentence convey this meaning, if not what are the mistakes?

Comment: Should the person who "points to A" also "match with B" or is there an additional person called the "user" involved?

Comment: @dubious the user must match! I guess my first sentence meant the person who points to A must match!!

Comment: @dubious could using "matching" in first sentece says that it's in continuation of what should be done.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, i think there's a better version of both sentences:
"I suggest that you point to what A should return and tell the user to match it with the output of B in README."

Here are my reasons:

1- when you're pointing to the content, you should use tell instead of say based on [the British Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/say-or-tell)
2- "you" after suggest in this sentence seems unessential and abundant.